# passing data without navigation in Ionic with Angular router

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a list which contains names of people, whenever I click to any of the items in the list, it will display to another page but not navigating to that path instead navigating to another page.

names.page.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list *ngFor='let listNames of people'>
    <ion-card (click)="passData(listNames)">
      <ion-card-header>
       <ion-card-title>{{ listNames.firstname }}</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

names.page.ts:

```
passData(listNames) {
  this.router.navigate(['/pages/details', listNames]);
}
```

details.page.ts:

```
export class DetailsPage implements OnInit {

 public fName;

 constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  const data = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('firstname');
  this.fname= data;
 }
}
```

I wanted to navigate to another screen after sending a data to display in details.page.html, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data using events class. It's used to pass data to any component/page without the navigation

```
import { Events } from '@ionic/angular';


constructor(public events: Events) { }
```

//Apply this code in received component/page

```
ngOnInit(){
this.events.subscribe('flag', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
});
```

}

//Use this code in data sender component/page

```
this.events.publish('flag', listNames);
```

Comment: try with JSON.stringify in console console.log(JSON.stringify(data))

Comment: should listNames instead of data?

Comment: data is a user-defined variable in success callback. So, you can change that variable as per your requirement

Comment: still doesn't log anything

Answer (score 0):

Are your parameters in `this.router.navigate()` correct? 
Below is the sample from [Angular- Routing, and navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router)

```
this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' }]);
```

It should look something like this, depending on where you run it:

```
localhost:4200/heroes;id=15;foo=foo
```

Check your one `this.router.navigate(['/pages/details, listNames]);` Looks like missing ' at the end of /pages/details

Hope this helps